# 2 almost identical Jquery codes, but only one works

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, json

So im designing the backend of a website for a club. You should be able to look at and edit tables with information. For now I only need 2 tables. One for the members and one for the events the club has. The members stuff works flawlessly, so I copy pasted the code, adapted some small stuff here and there and expected it to work for the events too. But it doesnt. And I cant find where I made a mistake.

So heres the JQuery for showing the Member-Table:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#personen").click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: '/website/administrator/components/com_backend/Personen_AJAX.php',
        success: function(data,status)
        {
          createTableByJqueryEach2(data);             
        },
        async:   true,
        dataType: 'json'
      }); 
    });
  });

  function createTableByJqueryEach2(data)
  {

  var eTable="<table><thead><tr><th colspan='5'>Created by for loop</th></tr><tr><th>Titel</th><th>Vorname</th><th>Name</th><th>Unternehmen</th><th>Gruppe</th</tr></thead><tbody>"
  $.each(data,function(index, row){
    // eTable += "<tr>";
    // eTable += "<td>"+(data)[i]['Titel']+"</td>";
    // eTable += "<td>"+(data)[i]['Vorname']+"</td>";
    // eTable += "<td>"+(data)[i]['Name']+"</td>";
    // eTable += "<td>"+(data)[i]['Unternehmen']+"</td>";
    // eTable += "<td>"+(data)[i]['Gruppe']+"</td>";
    // eTable += "</tr>";

    eTable += "<tr>";
    $.each(row,function(key,value){
      eTable += "<td>"+value+"</td>";
    });
    eTable += "</tr>";
  });
  eTable +="</tbody></table>";
  $('#eachTable').html(eTable);
}
```

And the PHP for showing the Member Table:

```
<?php 
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/website/dbConnection.php');

    function filterTable($searchquery)  
    {   
        $filter_Result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['connect'], $searchquery);
        return $filter_Result;
    }

    $searchquery = "SELECT Titel, Vorname, Nachname, Unternehmen, Gruppe FROM mitglieder";
    $searchresult = filterTable($searchquery) or die("Table cant be displayed");

    $data = mysqli_fetch_all($searchresult);
    echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

These 2 pieces of code work, but the next 2, which are almost identical dont.

Now the JQuery for showing me the Events-Table:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#anlaesse").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
          url: '/website/administrator/components/com_backend/Anlaesse_AJAX.php',
          success: function(data1,status)
          {
            createTableByJqueryEach(data1);
          },
          async:   true,
          dataType: 'json'
        });
    });
});

function createTableByJqueryEach(data1)
  {

  var eTable="<table><thead><tr><th colspan='4'>Created by for loop</th></tr><tr><th>Datum</th><th>Typ</th><th>Referent</th><th>Thema</th</tr></thead><tbody>";
  $.each(data1,function(index, row){
    // eTable += "<tr>";
    // eTable += "<td>"+(data1)[i]['Datum']+"</td>";
    // eTable += "<td>"+(data1)[i]['Typ']+"</td>";
    // eTable += "<td>"+(data1)[i]['Referent']+"</td>";
    // eTable += "<td>"+(data1)[i]['Thema']+"</td>";
    // eTable += "</tr>";

    eTable += "<tr>";
    $.each(row,function(key,value){
      eTable += "<td>"+value+"</td>";
    });
    eTable += "</tr>";
  });
  eTable +="</tbody></table>";
  $('#eachTable').html(eTable);
  }
```

And the PHP for showing me the Events-Table:

```
<?php 
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/website/dbConnection.php');

    function filterTable($searchquery)  
    {   
        $filter_Result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['connect'], $searchquery);
        return $filter_Result;
    }

    $searchquery = "SELECT Datum, Typ, Referent, Thema FROM events";
    $searchresult = filterTable($searchquery) or die("Tabelle kann nicht angezeigt werden");

    $data1 = mysqli_fetch_all($searchresult);
    echo json_encode($data1);

?>
```

I put in a parameter for failure in my JQuery, but removed it here for better code. The 2 errors were "parsererror" and "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input".

Also some important information:

First off my member table and events table. I had to censor a bit of the 2nd one as to not give away where I work/live/etc.

[image]

[image]

When I look into the dev-tool after requesting the event table the JSON Repsonse I get is empty. When I request the member table its an array with all the members from the database.

Thats about all the Information that there is and I have been working on this problem for hours. I need a 2nd pair of eyes to look at my code and point out what exactly it is that I am doing so wrong.

Id be thankful for any help!

Edit: So I put in the following code between $searchresult and $data1:

```
$array = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($searchresult)){
    $array[] = $row;
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($array); echo '</pre>';
```

And it gives me back the following Array:

[image]

Comment: Too many codes to check. Can you please post what is relevant?

Comment: What do you see as a response in a console for second ajax request?

Comment: @SougataBose The HTML is only there for gvining context to the Jquery and PHP. So you can safely ignore that unless you stumble, lets say on an id in the Jquery code and want to check what html component has that id.

Comment: @u_mulder The console doesnt give out any errors if thats what you mean. When I navigate to Network and press XHR I can see the JSON responses. The response for the Member request is an Array with the members from the database. The response for the Events request is empty.

Comment: Backtick `events` - `FROM \`events\``, though it is not reserved word, but still.

Comment: @u_mulder Did that. Obviously it didnt fix the problem, but Im always open to advice on how to improve my code (Since Im still a beginner) :).

Comment: Can I suggest you consider creating a [mcve]? You might even find the problem while you're doing that. The number of people who will spend time on your question is inversely proportional to the complexity of the code you post.

Comment: Off topic: Use jquery chaining rather than re-getting the jquery object.  In this case it's not much impact, but if your selector was more complicated it can save minutes (literaly!):  `$('#personen').css('cursor','pointer');$('#personen').html('Submit');$('#personen').removeAttr('disabled');` becomes `$('#personen').css('cursor','pointer').html('Submit').removeAttr('disabled');`

Comment: @peeebeee Thanks im new here. I tried editing my post the best I could, to increased visibility :)

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you for the advice!

Comment: Ignoring all the html/jquery, the key information here is that *"the JSON Response is empty"* - therefore your php is not returning anything (which then gives the parser error).  If you remove `dataType: 'json'` then you won't get a parser error but your data/data1 will be null.  So you need to determine why your events method returns nothing - have you tried the query directly in pgAdmin?

Comment: @freedomn-m I tested the PHP. I print_f'ed the $data1 array inbetween the last 2 lines of code. 

It spit out a perfectly normal array, with all the correct data. But then I put that Array into json_encode and it comes back empty for some reason.

edit: Also I didnt know what pgAdmin means and googled it. Do you mean the Open Source Tool? Does that come in handy during development? Should I download it?

Comment: pgAdmin: What are you currently using to view your database tables / make adhoc queries / test your sql?

Comment: At least you've found your culprit:  php's `json_encode`   - is there something "odd" about the data in the array that's returned?  (extra quotes/apostrophes maybe?)  It *should* handle it, but obviously isn't.

Comment: Aaaah. Yeah I use a MySql Database. So I navigated to the Database and copy pasted the query and it gave back the correct data. 

And a quick correction. I didnt printf $data1. I print_f'ed $seachresult. When I did so it showed me the Array with the correct data in it. 

So the mistake happens somewhere in the last 2 lines of code I assume?

Comment: @freedomn-m I updated the post. The Array looks correct to me. It has some german ä's, ö's and ü's it cant show (despite charset = utf-8 being in my html code). 

Could that be the problem?

Comment: @freedomn-m found the problem. The code indeed had issues processing the german letters. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  As a new member, it's difficult to gauge just how much info to provide to a question.   In this case, a little too much as most of it wasn't relevant. The next step is to determine exactly what's causing the problem and ask a targeted question - in this case you had already noted that the php wasn't returning anything - just hadn't identified that this was the issue - so all the javascript/html was irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well folks I found the problem.

I had some German letters like ä, ö and ü in the database entries, which confused my code.

Sorry for this messy post, which has too much irrelevant code and information. Im still new here and learning how to correctly post and Im also not that good at webdesign yet (Which is obvious considering my goddawful code).

Thank you to everyone that tried helping me!